# Why is it required to run the true command when you create a data-only container in Docker?

Tags: docker

I was reading some of the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) and I've noticed that they pass the `true` command when they create a container.

```
$ sudo docker create -v /dbdata --name dbdata training/postgres /bin/true
```

Why are they passing `/bin/true` to the container? If I understand correctly, my data-only container is never running, so is that even necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not necessary to *run* the command, but for right now Docker does require you to *specify* a command to run (or at least an entrypoint). I guess this is for schema-completeness reasons. The following command will create a docker container successfully:

```
docker create -v /dbdata --name dbdata --entrypoint=_ scratch
```

That container can be used as a volume container, but it can never run.

That said, many Docker utilities (such as Compose) [expect a command](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/942) to exist, because they will use `run`, not just `create` internally.

If you want to make very small containers for DVC purposes, use very small static binaries such as [tianon/true](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/tianon/true/).

Comment: A comment of yours mentioned that `_` is an invalid command, and therefore when set as an entrypoint causes the container to never be able to run (versus using `/bin/true` or something else). I just wanted to post that here because it is salient and illustrates your point very well.

Comment: Actually the command wasn't specified in the doc before, [I proposed to specify the true command to prevent accidential data loss](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/11210/files)